# How can I draw a line which is perpendicular to a line at a specific point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, mathematical-physics

I have a line. It can be counter clock-wise or clock wise on $x$-axis. But I want to draw a perpendicular line to it.  How can I do that? In the uploaded picture, I explain everything.

[image: perpendicular_line_diagram]

Comment: What do you mean by $147,424$? Are these coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Get the equation of your line,

And use,

> Eqn of line
>   $$ax+by+c=0$$
>   Eqn of line perpendicular
>   $$bx-ay+d=0$$

Find $\color{red}{d}$ for the perpendicular line passing through the point of intersection

by putting in x-coordinates and y-coordinates of point of intersection.

> Put x=147 in perpendicular line's equation and get y-coordinate of intersection.

Comment: i want to find the coordinates using equation

Answer (score 0):

Let your red start point be $(a^*, b^*)$ your line has the form. $y = \frac{-1}{m}x + c$ where $m = \tan(7.6^\circ)$.  You can figure out c since it passes through $(a^*, b^*)$.  Now, set x=0 to see that it meets the y-axis at $(c,0)$